# Cant put text beside instagram embed

Tags: html, css, html-helper

i want to put some text beside an instagram embed but i cant find how to do that
I would really appreciate the help

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de5ma.png)

heres the code: `codepen.io/chris8borg/pen/NWXdzNx`

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: That first article has a bullet made for this issue: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Answer (score 0):

make instgram icon and add comment in a div then make for them a parent to flex or grid them